# Green function - Issue with FFT automatically shifted

Tags: matlab, fft

I try to perform `FFT` on a `2D Green function` with a C code. My grid is `256x256` and I have taken `G(0,0)=1` to avoid divergence (`G(x,y)=-1/(4*pi*r)`) . Here's the plot of this Green function (got with absolute values, i.e with `G(x,y)=1/(4*pi*r)`) :

[image]

Now I get after `FFT` transformation the following figure :

[image]

I don't understand why I get this result, i.e why I get a centered figure (indeed, I have not shifted the `FFT`) ?

I should rather have a peak at `(kx , ky) = (0 , 0)` and a "`1/(k*k)`" for the rest of the plane because the Green function into Fourier space is :

```
G(kx , ky) = -1/(kx*kx+ky*ky)
```

I tried to reproduce this problem with Matlab; here's the code snippet :

```
t=-128:1:127
y = 1./(4*pi*sqrt(t.^2));
y(129) = 1.0;
figure(1);
plot(y);
title('Plot of 1D Green function'); 
z=fftshift(fft(y)); % Here I shift the FFT of y
figure(2);
plot(abs(z));
title('Plot of 1D FFT Green function');
```

I get the following figure for Green function 1D and its FFT :

[image]

FFT 1D shifted :

[image]

You can see that FFT 1D is centered around `n=129`, i.e shifted : this is normal because I have explicitly shifted the `FFT` with `fftshift Matlab function.`

On the second figure at the beginning of this post, why do I get a shifted FFT whereas I didn't shift the solution ?

Where could the error come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `plot(y)` without specifying the x-coordinate, so it is using the array indexes. Try using `plot(x,y)` where `x` are the kx and ky values.